how to get data from excel file using qmetry framework
I have a cucumber project with selenium and java and am trying to run my tests without multiple data values and I came across framework called qmetry however the documentation didn't help me much. I downloaded their project and I found this test
@P1 @Pass
Scenario Outline: Using QAF data-provider
Given I have a hello app with ""
When I ask it to say hi
Then it should answer with ""
Examples: {'key': 'demo.helloworld.dataset'}
Which exactly what I need to do except for getting data from excel and in the documentation they mentioned that they have annotations like
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/testdata.xls")
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/testdata.xls", sheetName="login")
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/testdata.xls", key="login") //excel with data table
does anyone can help me how to get the data from excel sheet (as dataprovider in selenium) with the help of qmetry framework and if you have any other solutions it will be fine too
I tried to download the example project however the project cannot recognize step definitions

it's a Map<String, String> if that helps.  You're right the docs don't help much.  You can do this in a more manual way using something like Apache POI: https://poi.apache.org/
